# Css selector - different level

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a big problem with coding on css

HTML

```
<div id='wrapper'>
     <div id='first'></div>
     ...
</div>
...
<div id='second'></div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
#first:hover ~ #second
{
     background:#000;
}
</style>
```

But it doesn't work. I need to change background of `div[id=second]` when the `div[id=first]` is hovered.

Comment: You cannot do it with CSS only, once you pop in an element you cannot pop out and select another, use JS or you need to alter your markup

Comment: You can't do that. Try doing it with js. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/82Nv7/

Comment: You'd have to change your mark-up so that the #first and #second divs are siblings. CSS doesn't have parent selectors or closures.

Answer (score 2):

Tilde `~` is the sibling selector, but `#second` is not the sibling of `#first` in your HTML. You need to place `#second` inside the wrapper for the `~` to work.

```
<style>
#first:hover ~ #second
{
     background:#000;
}
</style>

<div id='wrapper'>
    <!-- Now they share the same parent, so they are siblings -->
    <div id='first'>Hover over first</div>
    <div id='second'>To black out second</div>
</div>
```

If `#second` needs to be outside of `#wrapper` you must use Javascript to change the style of `#second` when the mouse is over `#first`. Plain CSS does not allow you to select "cousins".

```
<script>
    var third = document.getElementById('third'),
        fourth = document.getElementById('fourth');

    third.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        fourth.className = "blackout"
    });
    third.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        fourth.className = "";
    });
</script>

<style>
.blackout {
    background:#000;
}
</style>

<div id='wrapper2'>
    <div id='third'>Hover over third</div>
</div>
<div id='fourth'>To black out fourth</div>
```

[Check out the live demo in a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7u38/5/)

Comment: thnx, i realy know all the ways, but i was surprised enough when i realised that i couldn't get the parent of any in css, waiting for css4.